# Phusion Passenger consumes a lot of RAM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I have RoR app, which uses Passenger + Nginx.

Also I have ImageMagick for some regular tasks with images.

In one day (yesterday-tomorrow) I saw that my app crashes, in case out of memory!

ImageMagick write to log 'Cannot allocate memory'.

When I check free RAM, I saw that there only ~120MB free. (Summary is 1GB).

Most part used Passenger.

I had restarted it, and all became OK.

What reason of this can be?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, did you use all functions of ImageMagick, if not change ImageMagick to [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) (you save part of memory).
2. Next thing image processing, how do you work with images? Always you can do it asynchronously (resque/sidekiq/rake task in cron - "smaller solution"), you can maybe save some MB..
3. Passenger, is quite memory demanding. Try something smaller like Thin / Puma.
4. Are you sure, your code is without memory-leaks? If you're using ruby 2.1+ there is several tools to detect it, for example [excelent article](http://blog.skylight.io/hunting-for-leaks-in-ruby/), or if not, try to run your application in JRuby with Java memory profiler, for example [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)

some other question to think, did you really need full Rails? Rails is big and require quite a lot memory,  maybe [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) or for simple API Grape can be sufficient...

Comment: Thanks for nice reply!

1. It's a nice advice, I'll think about it.

2. It's method which calls when admin do some action in admin panel.

3. Oh. I read a lot of good responses about Passenger, but now I'll get info about others servers)

4. Will try first advise.

5. I really need Rails. Sinatra's abilities too small...

Comment: But main question is why Passenger doesn't return memory back?

Comment: Ive already wrote that, you dont provide much information. That's the reason why my answer is so general.. If you have memory-leaks free code (if passenger memory requirments raise, probably you don't have code without memory leaks, it can be in your code or in some of your gems), passenger will return memory back some times thats depends on GC and how much free-time server have....